# gradlew bintrayUpload Android library to jcenter

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

After I perform `gradlew bintrayUpload` to upload my Android library to jcenter, it's always at "Building 97%". I am in China. This is my CLI code:

```
ElasticLayout ➤ ./gradlew bintrayUpload                                                                                                                       git:master*
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:ellib:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:compileLint
:ellib:copyReleaseLint UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:checkReleaseManifest
:ellib:preDebugAndroidTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:preDebugUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:preReleaseUnitTestBuild UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:prepareReleaseDependencies
:ellib:compileReleaseAidl UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:compileReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:generateReleaseBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:mergeReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:compileReleaseShaders UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:generateReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:mergeReleaseAssets UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:generateReleaseResValues UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:generateReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:mergeReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:processReleaseManifest UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:processReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:generateReleaseSources UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:extractReleaseAnnotations UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:mergeReleaseProguardFiles UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:packageReleaseRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:packageReleaseResources UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:processReleaseJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:transformClassesAndResourcesWithSyncLibJarsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:mergeReleaseJniLibFolders UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:transformNative_libsWithMergeJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:transformNative_libsWithSyncJniLibsForRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:bundleRelease UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:javadoc UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:javadocJar UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:sourcesJar UP-TO-DATE
:ellib:install
Building 97% > :ellib:bintrayUpload
```

Comment: Not much detail there, you can try running the command with "--debug" option to get output which is more useful.

Comment: @OwaisAli here is command with "--debug" part of output:`14:24:25.102 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator] Connecting to 127.0.0.1:1080
14:24:25.137 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
14:24:25.137 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestProxyAuthentication] Proxy auth state: UNCHALLENGED
14:24:25.138 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnection] Sending request: CONNECT api.bintray.com:443 HTTP/1.1`> Building 97% > :ellib:bintrayUpload

Comment: @OwaisAli when i access **https://api.bintray.com:443** directly,my account can not authed,but when i access **https://bintray.com/**,my account can be authed,i don't know why

Comment: Just to make sure things are set up correctly, when you go to bintray.com you login with your email address and password right? The Bintray plugin (and the api.bintray.com URL) both require a user name (this is what shows up on the top right after you login to your bintray account) and an API key (Your Profile -> Edit -> API Key) - you can try revoking/creating a new API key if the current one is giving you issues.

Comment: @OwaisAli this is my android library github address:https://github.com/SharpChen/ElasticLayout, and i think my gradel file configure correctly,i'm sure i put right email address and password when i login,as i say,i can access bintray.com and login rightly.i generate a new API key just now,but the same problem show me.

Comment: @OwaisAli i think is the network error,i can't connect jcenter server in China

Comment: @OwaisAli i have solved it ,the problem is my Android Studio proxy setting problem, after 3 days,i have solved it,thanks! very thanks!

Comment: try adding flag with your command line command for more information as your CLI doesn't state much for now. Yoou can read following article to read all the steps needed to upload a library to Bintray and hence to Jcenter  in detailed manner....https://medium.com/@abhishekint16/upload-your-first-android-library-1892c23aea0f